# Spring-data-neo4j isn't indexing the entity id

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data

I have this @NodeEntity

```
@GraphId @Indexed
private Long id;
private String email;
private String password;
@Indexed
private String names;
private boolean registered;
```

However all fields are indexed (regardless of the annotations), except for the id property. I know that because I query the index with `*:*` and call `.getPropertyKeys()` on the returned `IndexHits`.

Is that a bug in SDN, or I should configure something different in order to make the ID be indexed as well. (On the other hand, using a `QueryResultBuilder` returns the entities with their IDs in place.

Answer (score 2):

`@GraphId` is provided by Neo4j (internal node-id), it is not indexable and you can use `repository.findOne()` or `template.getNode(id)` to look nodes up with that id.

I think you misunderstood: `IndexHit<Node>` returns the actual nodes and not the indexed fields.

How do you "query the index" ?